# function pointer with different parameter

Tags: c++

I program a Shell.

I have different functions with different parameters.

```
void func1(void);
void func2(char * x,);
void func3(char * x, string y);
```

At the moment a use a map to store string and pointer.

```
typedef map<string,void (*)()> t_list;
map<string,void(*)()>::iterator it;
t_list list;

list["argument1"]=&func1;
```

to find and start the function i use that:

```
it=list.find("argument");
if(it != list.end())
{
if->second();
}
```

Is it possible to store all functions with different parameters in the map? And how?

Comment: How do you intend to call these functions?  Do you expect to be able to inspect their actual signatures and match them with provided arguments?

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable solution for shell could be a function that takes a vector of strings and returns error code. So this single signature:

```
int (*func)(std::vector<std::string> const &args)
```

Then in the function you need to parse the arguments and you may call the real implementation (e.g. `void func3(char * x, string y);`)

Comment: or maybe int (\*func)(int argc, char\* argv[]);  =)

Comment: @wreckgar23: No, definitely not. That would be very unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use functors? They are easier to use and they are more OOP [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html).

Comment: Probably because that will not solve his problem. Even functor need to have a defined signature if you want to store it in a map.

Comment: But you can use virtual functors, and then pass parameters as separate structure. That should solve the problem, am I right?